# jsViews dynamic linking to a different item in array

Tags: templating, jsviews

I am trying to have a dynamic `if` linking to a property of a *different* item in an array.

My current code:

*Loader*

```
for (...) {

    var index = this.App.Data.Questions.push({
       ...
    }) - 1;

    if (CompareGuids(this.App.Data.Questions[index].QuestionId, '06EF685A-629C-42A5-9394-ACDEDF4798A5')) {
        this.App.PregnancyQuestionId = index;
    }
```

*Template*

```
{^{if ~root.Data.Questions[~root.PregnancyQuestionId].Response.ResponseText == "true"}}
   {{include #data tmpl="Clinical-History-QuestionWrapper-SingleQuestion"/}}
{{/if}}
```

It works for the initial loading, but it does not update.

*Note* I assume I could achieve this with a boolean property in `~root`, and then have a `$.observable(...).oberserve(...)` update this property, but I would prefer to have a direct access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is make sure that you are changing the `PregnancyQuestionId` observably. Just assigning a value cannot trigger data-linking to update the UI.

You need to write:

```
$.observable(this.App).setProperty("PregnancyQuestionId", index);
```

That should then trigger the binding correctly...

Comment: @mrs_sheep - if the above works for you, can you "accept' the reply, so others know it was the 'right answer'. Similarly for other questions you have asked in the past, some of which you never indicated whether the reply worked for you or not... Thanks!

Comment: It works. I will go through the other questions soon. Thanks for all the amazing and fast support!

Comment: One note for JSON users: The initial value of my `Response.ResponseText` was `"true"` or `"false"`, it later changed to `true` and `false` when modified through jsViews. I wrote a helper to catch this: `bool: function (value) {
        return value == true || value == "true";
    }`